# NodeJs doesn't redirect when changing Location header

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a pure NodeJs server and am trying to redirect the user. However, changing the location header doesn't help. In Chrome, I see that the response header has location and the code is 201 (I tried it with other codes, too), but Chrome (and neither does Edge) doesn't redirect. What am I doing wrong? Here is how I am trying to redirect (I made it as a server so it is easier to test for you):

```
const http = require("http");

function requestHandler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(201, {
        "Location": "/cats"
    });
}

function listeningHandler() {}

const app = http.createServer(requestHandler);

app.listen(5000, listeningHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `3XX` code to let the browser know a redirect is required. You are probably after a `302`.

Have a look at the HTTP status codes on this page for some more information.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages

Comment: It worked with 301, but shouldn't it also work with other codes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location says it should also work with 201 and all 3xx codes.

Comment: Edit: Thank you. I think I confused the location header's use in 201 and 3xx codes and probably didn't restart the server for the other codes I tested which were 3xx so I thought 3xx codes didn't work too. I don't know how I could have missed to do that but it seems only reasonable because I'm pretty sure I tried it with 302 and 303 and it didn't work when it works now.

Comment: That's great @asharpharp ! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you so others who find this question know.